# href link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am placing a piece of php code within a html page.  I am using href but the link is not working . here is my html+php piece of code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 space20">
           <button class="btn btn-green add-row">
             Add New <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
           </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sample_2">
    <?php 
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "hevak_neshat"; 
      $password = "shir moz peste";
      $dbname = "hevak_android_api";
    // Create connection 
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                                                                      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error){
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
      } 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM beacons";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);  
      if($result -> num_rows > 0)
      {
           echo "<thead>
                   <tr><th>Major number</th>
                       <th>Minor number</th>
                       <th>Client</th>
                       <th>Location</th>
                       <th>Link to ad</th>
                       <th>Attachment</th>
                       <th>Edit</th>
                   </tr> ;</thead>";
           echo "<tbody>";
           while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
           {
             echo "<tr><td>" .$row["major"]. "</td><td>" .$row["minor"]. "</td><td>" .$row["client"]. "</td><td>" .$row["geolocation"]. "</td><td>" .$row["linktoadd"].  "</td><td>" .$row["attacment"] . "</td><td>"; 
             echo  "<a href=\"#\" class =\"edit-row\" >";
             echo  "Edit";
             echo  "</a></td>";
             echo "</tr>";  
           }
           echo "</tbody></table>";
       } else {
           echo "no results";
       }
```

?>

and following is part of my .js code that is related to the html :

```
$('#sample_2').on('click', '.edit-row', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (actualEditingRow) {
            if (newRow) {
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(actualEditingRow);
                newRow = false;
            } else {
                restoreRow(oTable, actualEditingRow);

            }
        }
        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        editRow(oTable, nRow);
        actualEditingRow = nRow;

    });
    var oTable = $('#sample_2').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs" : [{
            "aTargets" : [0]
        }],
        "oLanguage" : {
            "sLengthMenu" : "Show _MENU_ Rows",
            "sSearch" : "",
            "oPaginate" : {
                "sPrevious" : "",
                "sNext" : ""
            }
        },
        "aaSorting" : [[1, 'asc']],
        "aLengthMenu" : [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],
        // set the initial value
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
    });
    $('#sample_2_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control input-sm").attr("placeholder", "Search");
    // modify table search input
    $('#sample_2_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("m-wrap small");
    // modify table per page dropdown
    $('#sample_2_wrapper .dataTables_length select').select2();
    // initialzie select2 dropdown
    $('#sample_2_column_toggler input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
        var iCol = parseInt($(this).attr("data-column"));
        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis(iCol, ( bVis ? false : true));
    });
};
return {
    //main function to initiate template pages
    init : function() {
        runDataTable_example1();
        runDataTable_example2();
    }
};
```

My exact problem is when I remove the php part "Edit" is clickable and works correctly. but when i place the php so i can be able fetch my database data, "Edit" is still a link but when you click on it nothing happens.
I cannot find the cause of this problem

Update:
here is my browser provided html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12 space20">
                                                <button class="btn btn-green add-row">
                                                    Add New <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="table-responsive"> 
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sample_2">

                                <thead> 
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Major number</th>
                                                        <th>Minor number</th>
                                                        <th>Client</th>
                                                        <th>Location</th>
                                                        <th>Link to ad</th>
                                                        <th>Attachment</th>
                                                        <th>Edit</th>

                                                    </tr> 
                                                </thead><tbody><tr><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>noxel</td><td>16253</td><td>www.noxel.com</td><td>test</td><td><a href='#' class ='edit-row' >Edit<script>
$(document).on("click","edit-row",function(event){

alert("m here");
});
</script></a></td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>9</td><td>nox</td><td>123456</td><td>www.digikla.com</td><td>jhhfdbc</td><td><a href='#' class ='edit-row' >Edit<script>
$(document).on("click","edit-row",function(event){

alert("m here");
});
</script></a></td></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>fgfh</td><td>645312</td><td>wwwwwwwwwwwww</td><td>wwwwwwwww</td><td><a href='#' class ='edit-row' >Edit<script>
$(document).on("click","edit-row",function(event){

alert("m here");
});
</script></a></td></tr></tbody>
                                            </table>                                            

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- end: PAGE CONTENT-->
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- end: PAGE -->
            </div>
```

Comment: Question. What happens if you replace your PHP for a simple echo "Testing"? This could help you find out if this has something to do with an error in database connection or other problems in the PHP.

Comment: Jorge database is working completely fine. code fetches my data correctly.

Comment: Rayon how can I know that is getting fired? can you explain more?

Comment: What does the browser console show??

Comment: this is what brower console says Akshay :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jumpTo' of  subview-example.js:482 undefined.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I see there is a ';' in your first  `echo` statement in `php` code after `<tr>`, will that make any difference?

Comment: Hemang what you mentioned does make sense, I omit ; , save my code on the server, but when I go to my url and click 'view page source' there is still a ; in front of </tr>! but I am pretty sure that I omit that.

Comment: mina i remember that name.

Comment: When console found out Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property meaning that your have problem with your js. try replace example
$(document).on('click', 'a.edit-row', function(e) .. I dont know if it's correct.

Comment: anyway mina name just like my ex-gf name :'( .. miss her alot

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz about the answer I should say that it did not work, and about the ex I must say I am sorry :-)

Comment: @mina well here it goes..

Comment: @mina let me know if you got the answer :)

Comment: @mina, How bad does that look :( Why are you binding events in loop ?

Comment: @mina :first check do you get the required HTML page .... I think you are going wrong somewhere in middle . Its a wrong practice to write js scripts in d middle of html codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You need not to write `script` in `php-loop`. Also note that `".edit-row"` is valid selector for classes not `"edit-row"`

Do not forget to prevent the default behaviour of `<a>` elements. Use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Put your `script` right before closing of body(`</body>`) tag.

Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit-row", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("m here");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 space20">
      <button class="btn btn-green add-row">
        Add New <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sample_2">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Major number</th>
          <th>Minor number</th>
          <th>Client</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Link to ad</th>
          <th>Attachment</th>
          <th>Edit</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>noxel</td>
          <td>16253</td>
          <td>www.noxel.com</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td><a href='#' class='edit-row'>Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>nox</td>
          <td>123456</td>
          <td>www.digikla.com</td>
          <td>jhhfdbc</td>
          <td><a href='#' class='edit-row'>Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>fgfh</td>
          <td>645312</td>
          <td>wwwwwwwwwwwww</td>
          <td>wwwwwwwww</td>
          <td><a href='#' class='edit-row'>Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/asobo3fn/)

Comment: finally it works! I have added  var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
          if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {                  
              $.each(currentTD, function () {
                  $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
              });
          } else {
             $.each(currentTD, function () {
                  $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
              });
          }

          $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit')

Comment: i have added code above at the end of your suggestion and it is working. thank you for the help:-)

Comment: Yes, to make fields editable, that was needed.. I will not mind if you upvote.. Happy Coding !

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your js code function `$('#sample_2').on('click', '.edit-row', function(e) {` with `

> $(document).on('click', '#sample_2 a.edit-row', function(e) {

OR SIMPLY

> $(document).on('click', 'a.edit-row', function(e) {

this might work for your

Comment: @RayonDabre i donno why, i replace this part of code and still when i click on button nothing happens.

Comment: @mina, I suggest you to provide browser rendered html so that it will be easier to debug..

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure that delegated event handlers would help: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Try these changes:

```
echo  "<a href='#' class ='edit-row' >";


$(document).on("click",".edit-row",function(event){

alert("m here");
});
```

Comment: put a alert and return false ,, and check this should work

Comment: I put an alert first line in $(document).on('click', '#sample_2 a.edit-row', function(e) {alert"something"} , but still when I click on the edit button nothing shows up. not even the alert. why?

Comment: I even did this but still when I click on the edit button nothing happens, checkout my next comment.

Comment: echo"<button onClick=\"My_Function\">Edit</button>";

Comment: and put this at the end of my code:  <script>function My_Function() {alert("I am an alert box!");}</script>

Comment: try above changes in your code , check my answer edit

Comment: i did that, still nothing, going crazy:-(

Answer (score 1):

change your top javascript code to this and check.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit-row', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (actualEditingRow) {
            if (newRow) {
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(actualEditingRow);
                newRow = false;
            } else {
                restoreRow(oTable, actualEditingRow);

            }
        }
        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        editRow(oTable, nRow);
        actualEditingRow = nRow;
    });
```

Comment: check by putting above code in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: also show code where you initialized these variables actualEditingRow, newRow. And check by putting alert aswell

Comment: @ImranQamer, __OP__ stands for _Original Poster_ or _Asker_